# Angular Universal page loading/refreshing issue

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have added Angular Universal in my project(upgraded to angular 8). Which is comparatively a big project. After solving all the window, jquery and localstorage issue I have successfully able to run the app. But the problem is, the server runs on localhost:4000. when I type localhost:4000 in browser nothing happens. But if I put localhost:4000/index.html, It starting to load fine and return to base localhost:4000. Then every angular route works fine. But if I try to refresh any page it doesn't load anything.

my server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
// ssr DOM
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join('dist/browser', 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
Object.defineProperty(win.document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});
// mock documnet
global['document'] = win.document;
// othres mock
global['CSS'] = null;
// global['XMLHttpRequest'] = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
global['Prism'] = null;


import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
if (mainModule && mainModule.filename === __filename) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

I think i need some change with this file to load correctly.

Comment: Have  you solved this issue ?  or you still have

Comment: No, I haven't solved it yet. Any suggestion? @AbolfazlR

Comment: I still have the same problem ....

Comment: Same issue here. Couldn't find any fix right now. I found this but didn't help : https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/965